# RoR: rendering devise login into application layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, render

I'm trying to render devise sign in page from "devise/sessions/new" into my application layout, but I'm wondering how to do so?

If i do this:

```
<%= render "devise/sessions/new" %>
```

I get an error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Static#index
Missing partial devise/sessions/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
```

if I try this:

```
<%= render :template => "devise/sessions/new" %>
```

I get an error:

```
NameError in Users#show
undefined local variable or method `resource'
```

Where I have this as a form:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

I'm just trying to bring the sign in form into my application layout, if its possible.

Answer (score 1):

Whats the name you have used for sign in page.
if its as - "new.html.erb", then rename it to "_new.html.erb".
then,

```
<%= render "devise/sessions/new" %>
```

will work.

for second issue, that will be coming again after above thing.

```
NameError in Users#show
undefined local variable or method `resource'
```

as can see, no variable can be found in 'show' action, you need to define a variable. From which, form will get some data.
go through, forms and flow for rails app, once again.